# Elasticsearch - Remove field from a structure

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am using Elasticsearch 6.5.
Let say, that my Elasticsearch document looks like this:

```
"_source" : {
    "field1" : "val1",
    "field2" : "val2",
    "struct1" : {
      "inner_field1" : "inner val1",
      "inner_field2" : "inner val2",
    }
  }
```

I would like to delete one of inner fields in this structure.
I tried following code:

```
POST test_idx1/_doc/1/_update
{
 "script": "ctx._source.remove('struct1.inner_field1');"
}
```

and the result says `updated`, but nothing changes.
How to perform such action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the **field** from all the existing document by this way,

```
POST test_idx1/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.struct1.remove('inner_field1')",
    "query" : {
        "exists": { "field": "struct1.inner_field1" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps:

`GET test_idx1/_doc/1`

Then pass up `struct1` with `inner_field1` removed as a partial document update:

```
POST test_idx1/_update/1
{
    "doc" : {
        "struct1" : {
            "inner_field2" : "inner val2",
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution can be very slow. What if `struct1` have few dozens of fields and I need to delete only one of them?

Comment: Are you sure struct1 needs to be an object then? It might better to model the fields as `struct1-innerfield1` etc, without nesting them. This would simplify your queries and updates.